# Android: Sidebar with two scrollable menu's in the same vertical space?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a menu that pops out the left of the screen after a button press, and when it comes out, it reveals two scrollable views, one big one ontop and a smaller one below it. IS there anything like this, any source code I can look at, and if not, how would I go about making this?

Comment: Have you tried using two scroll views ?

Comment: ah, seems like I formatted the scrollview wrong when I had two of them, so I had ditched that idea. fixed it and works great now, thanks.